# Летучий голландец — прописная или строчная

Tags: прописная-строчная

Подскажите, пожалуйста, уместно ли написание фразеологизма "летучий голландец" со строчной буквы? Спасибо!

Comment: Какой-либо фразеологизм, начинающийся с пропиской, встречался?

Answer (score 1):

В книге "Современный русский литературный язык" указано написание с маленькой буквы.

[image]
[https://books.google.com/books?id=x8x6DQAAQBAJ&pg=PA152&lpg=PA152&dq=летучий+голландец](https://books.google.com/books?id=x8x6DQAAQBAJ&pg=PA152&lpg=PA152&dq=%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9+%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%86)

Это можно объяснить тем, что, являясь фразеологизмом, фраза передаёт уже не название уникального корабля, а качество человека.

Значение:
1. О постоянно путешествующем, странствующем человеке, скитальце.
2. О непоседливом, беспокойном, постоянно суетящемся человеке (часто шутл.).

Происхождение:
Выражение восходит к средневековой легенде о капитане, поклявшемся в бурю обогнуть мыс, преграждающий путь, хотя бы это стоило ему жизни и длилось вечность. За свою гордыню он был наказан судьбой: призрак капитана и его призрачный корабль носятся с тех пор по морю вечно. У моряков считается дурной приметой увидеть его на своем пути. В немецком и в других современных европейских языках выражение стало популярным благодаря опере Вагнера "Летучий голландец".